# How to access element in object?

Tags: jquery

For example i have:

```
var my_ul = jQuery('<ul/>');
jQuery('<li/>').appendTo(my_ul);
jQuery('<li/>').appendTo(my_ul);
jQuery('<li/>').appendTo(my_ul);
jQuery('<li/>').appendTo(my_ul);
```

Is it possible to access last li in ul?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
my_ul.find('li:last');
```

Or alternatively, you can use context parameter of jquery constructor:

```
$('li:last', my_ul);
```

See [**demo**](http://tinker.io/74614)

Answer (score 0):

try this

`my_ul.find('li:last');`

Answer (score 0):

Naturally!

This is the real magic behind jQuery: selectors. I strongly recommend you to read up on all of them, as they all have a purpose, and some of them are pretty, pretty powerful. If you're into performance/optimization, also make a note of the emulated pseudo-selectors, as they're usually slower.

To answer your question directly, all of the following code will get you the last item in your ul:

```
my_ul.children("li:last");

my_ul.children("li").last();
```

Exercise for the reader: find which one is more performant :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_ul = jQuery('<ul/>');
x1 = jQuery('<li/>').appendTo(my_ul);
x2 = jQuery('<li/>').appendTo(my_ul);
x3 = jQuery('<li/>').appendTo(my_ul);
x4 = jQuery('<li/>').appendTo(my_ul);

x4.html('I\'m last');
```

You can access what element you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_ul = $('<ul/>');
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  my_ul.append("<li> index: "+i+"</li>");
}

alert( my_ul.find('li:last').text() ); // .find() faster than constructor
```